# How to fetch sorted objects with duplicates filtered out in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

This is my collection:

```
{ num: 4, title: "alpha", data: 7538 }
{ num: 2, title: "beta", data: 7538 }
{ num: 7, title: "beta", data: 7538 }
{ num: 5, title: "alpha", data: 7538 }
```

I want MongoDB to sort them first by `num` and **then** ignore duplicates in `title`. I'm expecting:

```
{ num: 2, title: "beta", data: 7538 }
{ num: 4, title: "alpha", data: 7538 }
```

Which function do I need to use? I suspect it's [`aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/), but how exactly to use it?

Comment: If you want group a field, you could use [MongoDB AF](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you have to use the Aggregation Framework. Below is an example of how use AF to achieve the expected result, considering that you want to sort `num` in `ASC` manner.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {
        "$group" : {
            _id : "$title",
            num : { "$min" : "$num" },
            data : { "$first" : "$data" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort" : { "num" : 1 }
    }
)
```

Here you are basically grouping the documents by its `title`, getting the minimal value of `num` and the first value of `data`. If you want to sort in `DESC` manner, use `$max` instead of `$min` on `num` field and use `-1` on the `$sort` pipeline phase.

Comment: wouldn't it be more efficient to sort on num first and then use $first for num as well as data?  Especially since if there is an index on num it will then be used.

Comment: indeed, sorting should go first

Comment: Actually, use $sort first will not order the results properly. If you try with the dataset that you provided, the `num : 4` document will become first.